# Selecting a dynamic sidebar via metabox in wordpress

Tags: metabox, sidebar

I am developing a wordpress theme where are 3 sideboxes. I want to select a sidebox through metabox in my admin page so that particular sidebar shows up in front-end.

My codes are:-

In function

```
array(
                'name'    => __( 'Select Sidebar', 'cmb' ),
                'desc'    => __( 'Select Your sidebar', 'cmb' ),
                'id'      => $prefix . 'test_select',
                'type'    => 'select',
                'options' => array(
                    array( 'name' => __( 'sidebar-1', 'cmb' ), 'value' => 'sidebar-1', ),
                    array( 'name' => __( 'sidebar-2', 'cmb' ), 'value' => 'sidebar-2', ),
                    array( 'name' => __( 'sidebar-3', 'cmb' ), 'value' => 'sidebar-3', ),
                ),
            ),
```

In my theme file :-

```
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

and in my sidebar.php

```
 <?php do_action( 'before_sidebar' ); ?>
        <?php 

           global $post;

           $sidebar = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cmb_test_select', true); ?>


        <?php if ( $sidebar != 'sidebar-1' ) :  ?>

                 <?php ! dynamic_sidebar( $sidebar = 'sidebar-1');  ?>
  <div></div>

<?php  elseif( $sidebar != 'sidebar-2') : ?>

         <?php  ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' )) ?>
          <aside>


          </aside>

          <?php  elseif( $sidebar != 'sidebar-3')   :?>

          <?php  ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-3' )) ?>

          <aside>


          </aside>





        <?php endif; ?>
```

But when I select the relevant sidebar in the admin page the same sidebar is not showing in front-end. 
Please help me to sort out where I am going wrong

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems a little superfluous; I'm pretty sure you could compact it to simply:

```
<?php

do_action( 'before_sidebar' );

if ( ! $sidebar = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_cmb_test_select', true ) )
    $sidebar = 'sidebar-1'; // Default sidebar if meta value does not exist.

if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( $sidebar ) ) : ?>

    <!-- No widgets for selected sidebar, display any default content here. --> 

<?php endif ?>
```